# Accessing the second element of a list for every row in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My data consist of Latitude in object type :

```
0        4.620881605
1        4.620124518
2        4.619367709
3        4.618609512
4         4.61784758
```

Then, I split after the decimal point using this code:

```
marker['Latitude'].str.split('.')
```

Resulting in :

```
0        [4, 620881605]
1        [4, 620124518]
2        [4, 619367709]
3        [4, 618609512]
4         [4, 61784758]
```

which is good but not quite there yet. **I want to access the second element of the list for every row** and the end result I am expecting is this :

```
0        620881605
1        620124518
2        619367709
3        618609512
4         61784758
```

Comment: You want to keep the value after the decimal as an intenger?

Comment: I think string is suitable because then I need to use match these value with user input. Say, at least 5 initial number from input matches these value and output the result. Though I am not sure if integer will work better ..

Comment: Hmm, what’s the use for this? It seems unusual, no?

Comment: Hmm I think I overthink. For example, user input '1.23456' (5 decimal place-OK) but in my dataframe, I have '1.2345678'. In this case, technically it matches but logically it does not. So this is what I try to achieve. First, I split from decimal point. Then, match the value after decimal with value after decimal point from user. Lastly, output the actual latitude.

Comment: _(5 decimal place-OK)_ Is there an incorrect number of decimal places? Why are users entering these values in the first place? If these are numbers, why not treat them as such?

Comment: Due to accuracy of latitude itself. 5 decimal places is sufficient to say a location pretty accurate. I can't expect user will input the exact value like in my dataframe and not all latitude in my dataframe has fixed 8 decimal points for instance. But they're certainly 5 and above.

Comment: Alright, I don’t even know why I asked that, since input validation isn’t related to this situation lol

Comment: Try chain that with `str[1]`

Comment: @dee So in the end, should you actually treat them as numbers?

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for an answer to the same question, it seems there is nothing built-in. The best option I can find is `operator.itemgetter()`, which is implemented in native code and should perform fine with `Series.apply()`:

```py
from operator import itemgetter

series = pd.Series(["%s|%s" % (-x, x) for x in range(100)])
pairs = series.str.split('|')

# Fetch all the negative numbers
negatives = pairs.apply(itemgetter(0)).astype(int)

# Fetch all the positive numbers
positives = pairs.apply(itemgetter(1)).astype(int)
```

Note `Series.str.split()` also accepts an `expand=True` argument, which returns a new `DataFrame` containing columns 0..n rather than a series of lists. This probably should be the default behaviour, it's much easier to work with:

```py
series = pd.Series(["%s|%s" % (-x, x) for x in range(100)])
pairs = series.str.split('|', expand=True)

# Fetch all the negative numbers
negatives = pairs[0]

# Fetch all the positive numbers
positives = pairs[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work as long as all of the lists in the column have at least two elements:

```
# generate example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': [[4, 620881605], [4, 620124518], [4, 619367709]]})

# retrieve the second item in every list
decimals = df_test['c1'].apply(lambda x: list(x)[1])
```

The decimals object now contains a series with all of the decimal values. You could also make this a new column as follows:

```
df['decimals'] = df_test['c1'].apply(lambda x: list(x)[1])
```

Answer (score -2):

```
marker['Latitude'].apply(lambda x : x.strip(',').split('.')[1])
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Comment: Users find it difficult to understand code only answers with no explanation. Please add some description explaining what is does and how it solves the problem or add comments in the source code at appropriate places.

Answer (score -3):

You can use `pd.DataFrame.iterrows()` to iterate by row and then select the proper index for your list.

```
import pandas as pd

x = pd.DataFrame({'a':[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]})

for index, row in x.iterrows():
    print(row['a'][1])

2
4
6
```

Comment: It’s `pandas.DataFrame.iterrows()`, no? In any case, why use `.iterrows()`for this?

Comment: Sorry, I tried this before and it does not work. I give me error: `'Series' object has no attribute 'iterrows'`

Comment: Did you try the code? It works for me as written. @AMC This was the first idea that came to mind, what other solution do you have?

Comment: @dee Try to google that error message, or look at the Pandas docs.

Comment: Yes. See : `y = marker['Latitude'].str.split('.')` then `for index, row in y.iterrows():
    print(row['Latitude'][1])` I am still receiving the above error.

Comment: @dee The code is correct, look at the error message, the type of the object in the code by bwc, and the type of the object you’re trying to use the method on.

Comment: I figured. I use series in loop while you use dataframe. But this @Quang Hong produced my expected result. Thank you

Comment: @dee _But this Quang Hong produced my expected result._ That's not important if you still haven't thought about whether you should even be treating them like strings.

Comment: I treated them as float @AMC

Comment: @dee How did you compare them?